# Store event queue until create listener

Tags: node.js, events, event-handling

I have system that sends many events with some data, when it is avaible. I want to store them in memory till create listener, that takes one event data and die.

I think it should be some event in memory queue. Dont wanna use additional storage like Redis.

Advice me pattern or maybe module that helps to do that in a proper way.

Comment: what kind of info should be stored, provide example, please.

Comment: Free ip address. So just a string. The other side in some interval will be launch another service that set listener and waits for free ip address, take it and shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, didn't notice you don't want any additional storage. So you should use just the type of queue that fits your needs.

So basically you create a small module, handling your needs. 
Let's image you need a stack type queue. Than your module would be simple:

```
module.exports = {
  // storage
  _stack: [],

  // add event
  push: data => this._stack.push(data),

  // fetch event
  pop: () => {
    if (!this._stack.length) return null;
    return this._stack.pop();
  }
};
```

In case of another queue type, solution would be a little more complex.

**Update:**
But in case if multiple services, maybe you should look into some storage. One service puts data - another fetches. And if case if any of them fails - your data will stay alive.